# Adding two affiliation for one author

Tags: affiliation

I want to have author list with all the names on top and then the affiliation appears after them . Similar to below:
[image]

and then I want to add two affiliation for one author. How should I do this? and I also would like to add the footnote of 'these authors contributed equally' for some authors.
I would be very grateful if you could help me as I have an approaching deadline.

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{G A\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
C H\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
D G\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
M M\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},\\
J M\IEEEauthorrefmark{4},
A A\IEEEauthorrefmark{5, 4},%~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~IEEE}.  %%%this method doesn't work
J K\IEEEauthorrefmark{6},
J B\IEEEauthorrefmark{7},
M H\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Electrical, Computer, and System Engineering,
Case Western Reserve University, }
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Digital Inc., USA}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}College }
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Medical Center}%
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{5}School of Medicine,USA}%<-this % stops an unwanted space%%%%%%%%
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{6}Cancer Center, USA}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{7}Design, USA}
```